# how to mask cloud url of a file using PHP?

Tags: php, url, download, mask

suppose I have a shared file from google drive like this:

```
https://google_drive_link_to_shared_my_file.zip
```

and I have a website like this:

```
https://example.com
```

How can I create a script that masks the file download link to something like this:

```
https://example.com/download/my_file.zip
```

and I don't what to download the file to my server and then give users the link to downloaded file in my server. I want to just hide the actual URL to the file so that users won't notice the actual source of the file.

Comment: *"I don't what to download the file to my server"* - You might not have to *save* the file on your server, but you would need to at least *stream* the contents from the source to the user.  So you're still going to have to consume your server's bandwidth for twice the size of the file, once to get it from Google and once to serve it to the user.  I'm on the fence about marking as a duplicate, but a Google search for "php stream file from remote server" finds a variety of possible solutions to accomplish this.

Comment: @David Thank you. How about redirecting? Is it possible to achieve this using a redirect?

Comment: Redirecting to what exactly?  On a technical level, what specifically are you trying to achieve?  Essentially there are two options: (1) Give the target URL to the client so they can download the content; or (2) Hide the target URL from the client and serve them the content from your server.  There's no way for the client to download from a URL without knowing that URL.